# Securing Macbooks in an Enterprise Environment

Tags: macos, user-management, healthcare, administration, provisioning

I have been looking online at different forums/websites but was not able to find a direct answer. Does a checklist/process or software exist to secure Macbook computers in a enterprise environment( Healthcare ). Ex: disabling usb and or cd drives, Not allowing specific users to install software.

Comment: Maybe helpful http://9to5mac.com/2013/11/27/how-google-manages-over-40000-macs-without-much-help-from-apple/

Comment: How are this rules specific to Mac?

Comment: I feel like this question is akin to "how do I avoid dying?" in how broad it is. I'm voting to close in order to tell future visitors to this page that any answer is almost certainly incomplete / outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have JAMF Casper Suite, you can utilize the script infrastructure built by many of the following developers and projects:

- https://github.com/JAMFSupport
- https://github.com/loceee/OSXCasperScripts
- https://github.com/rtrouton?tab=repositories

If you use a different Enterprise agent suite, such as [Munki](https://github.com/munki/munki), LANDesk, Puppet, Chef, Centrify, et al, you may just want to check out the generic resources at -- https://github.com/macjustice/awesome-macadmin

For one-at-a time installations of secure standards, be sure to check out the [Lockdown UI](https://objective-see.com/products/lockdown.html), as well as the [original post](https://summitroute.com/blog/2015/12/29/osxlockdown/).

There is also a book, Enterprise Mac Security: El Capitan, Third Edition

Comment: There are also the Center for Internet Security Benchmarks -- https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/browse/index.cfm?category=benchmarks.os.unix.osx -- but the latest is from Nov 2015 for OS X 10.11 -- https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/osx/CIS_Apple_OSX_10.11_Benchmark_v1.0.0.pdf

Comment: Here are some recent conferences talking about Apple Enterprise Security -- http://macadmins.psu.edu/conference/resources/ -- http://www.macdevops.ca/presentations/